# Alternative to Tomcat 9 AJP connector for connecting Apache server with Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat9, ajp

The application is using Single sign-on and previously we were using tomcat v7 AJP connector to connect Apache server with tomcat. After upgrading to Tomcat v9, the AJP connector is disabled by default in server.xml

```
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               address="::1"
               port="8009"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Will uncommenting this property solve the issue? Also I have read that AJP is disabled due to vulnerabilities :

https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/Addressing-the-Apache-Tomcat-JServ-Protocol-AJP-Security-Vulnerability?language=en_US

If that is the case then is there an alternative to connect Apache server with Tomcat? Does this impact single sign-on functionality? Also, is there any configuration that can be done to mitigate the vulnerability and still use AJP?

Comment: I think most folks use a [reverse proxy](https://tecadmin.net/setup-apache-as-reverse-proxy-for-tomcat/) these days.

Comment: Are Tomcat and Apache on the same host?

Comment: No There on different machines

Comment: Then you might look at [Christopher's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUjUEvGFstI) on how to switch from AJP to HTTP.